# Angular 6 - how to create a component and nest multiple divs inside it

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to create a search drop down component which can be reuse. When i pull data from the database i can display it in a drop down menu and if i need add a button that will display it in a textarea or add it to a list depending on what i need. I have seen some examples like clarity design modal But i cant seem to figure how they do it. an example

```
<search-component>
   <div *ngFor="let info of infos">
      {{info}}
   </div>
<div>[display selected item here]</div>
</search-component>
```

I have made one before but the search is coupled to that component and i have to create many components with different ways to display the data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if i understood correctly, the search-component is written by you? And you want to put in some custom HTML? Then you simply need to add `<ng-content></ng-content>` into your searchComponent where you want to add your customized code.

Comment: Yeah i figure it out and yes it is use ng-content

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with `<ng-container>`:

```
<search-component>
   <ng-container>
     <div *ngFor="let info of infos">
       {{info}}
     </div>
     <div>[display selected item here]</div>
  </ng-container>
</search-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

In the search-component html i add

```
<ng-content select=".content"></ng-content>
```

then when i use search-component

i do

```
<search-component> 
<div class="content">
   <div *ngFor="let info of infos">
      {{info}}
   </div>
<div>[display selected item here]</div>
</div>
</search-component>
```

and it works